# Getting all posts that belong to one user in Node / Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have 2 models User & Revive as you can see below... in the router(see below) what is the query to get all revives that belong to the user/creator to display on his dashboard/profile page?

User Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Revive Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var reviveSchema = new Schema({
    reviveTitle: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    reviveStory: {
        type: String
    },
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        }
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Revive', reviveSchema);
```

Router:

```
router.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
   code ?? to get all revives that belong to the creator/user only ??
    res.render('users/dashboard', {currentUser: req.user});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the mongoose addition Dima :) Any clues on the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would setup the Revive schema  bit differently:

```
author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"}
```

Then you should be able to just do a proper find:

```
const Revive = mongoose.model('Revive');

router.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    Revive.find({author:req.user._id}, (e, revives) => {
       // however you handle errors goes first
       res.render('users/dashboard', {currentUser: req.user, revives: revives});
    });
});
```